# react native ios emulator - how do I test camera function on computer, without using a phone?

Tags: react-native, android-emulator, android-camera, react-native-ios

I implemented code using a React Native package accessing camera to scan documents. I don't have a physical phone. How do I test the functionality using just my ios emulator on computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For iOS it's impossible to test the camera. For Android you can configure the emulator to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Its possible to configure your emulator in Android to test the camera:

1. fire up Android Studio
2. open the AVD Manager screen
3. click on the pencil icon next to your chosen emulator device
4. show advanced settings
5. change camera (front and/or back) to "Webcam0"

You will need to cold restart your emulator for the changes to take effect.